# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm getting this error: `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string` when I try to run the following query in SQL server 2008 R2:

```
    DECLARE @Time datetime = N'7/13/2011'
    DECLARE @str as varchar(100) = '2011_07_13_DM_VT_I2_Data'
    DECLARE @TestTime datetime =  cast(replace (left (left(@str, len(@str) - len('_data')), 10), '_', '') as datetime)
    DECLARE @r int = datediff(d, @TestTime, @Time)

    SELECT t.name FROM
    (
    SELECT 
         name
    FROM 
        sysobjects 
    WHERE 
        (type = 'U') AND ((name LIKE '%[_]I2[_]Data') or (name LIKE '%[_]R4[_]Data') or (name LIKE '%[_]R8[_]Data'))
    ) t

    WHERE
        datediff(DAY, cast(replace (left (left(t.name, len(t.name) - len('_data')), 10), '_', '') as datetime), @Time) <= 1

    ORDER BY 
        cast(replace (left (left(t.name, len(t.name) - len('_data')), 10), '_', '') as datetime) desc
```

This query runs fine if I comment out `WHERE datediff(DAY, cast(replace (left (left(t.name, len(t.name) - len('_data')), 10), '_', '') as datetime), @Time) <= 1`, then I wonder if it is the problem of the `cast` function. But the `t` table will have the table names like `'2011_07_13_DM_VT_I2_Data'` you can see in the `@TestTime` the `cast` function works fine with this format. I don't know what is the wrong with the `WHERE` condition.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split your query into two because it looks like the query optimizer has decided to apply the where clause from the outer query before it has filtered down the rows from sysobjects in the sub query.

You could try something like this.

```
DECLARE @Time datetime = N'7/13/2011'
DECLARE @str as varchar(100) = '2011_07_13_DM_VT_I2_Data'
DECLARE @TestTime datetime =  cast(replace (left (left(@str, len(@str) - len('_data')), 10), '_', '') as datetime)
DECLARE @r int = datediff(d, @TestTime, @Time)

SELECT name INTO #TMP
FROM 
    sysobjects 
WHERE 
    (type = 'U') AND ((name LIKE '%[_]I2[_]Data') or (name LIKE '%[_]R4[_]Data') or (name LIKE '%[_]R8[_]Data'))

SELECT *
FROM #TMP as t
WHERE
    datediff(DAY, cast(replace (left (left(t.name, len(t.name) - len('_data')), 10), '_', '') as datetime), @Time) <= 1

ORDER BY 
    cast(replace (left (left(t.name, len(t.name) - len('_data')), 10), '_', '') as datetime) desc

DROP TABLE #TMP
```

Comment: I tried to replace 10 with 11 in the CAST function but still the same error. But your query above works fine for me. There is actually no padding in the table names, the tables all start with 2011 without any prefix. It's odd.. But your query works for me, that is all matters for now. Thank you!

Comment: @zdev - Yes of course. I forgot that you could use brackets to create table with names like that `[2011_07_13_DM_VT_I2_Data]`. Then you can go back to use 10 instead of 11. It should still work. The reason it works with 11 as well is because you remove the last `_` with the `replace`. I have updated the answer. The split of the query and use of a temp table is what fixed it for you.

Comment: I tried to use `(type = 'U') AND (name LIKE '%[_]Data')` in my original query it magically works fine, so I'm confused, the `%[_]Data` should filter less rows than using `((name LIKE '%[_]I2[_]Data') or (name LIKE '%[_]R4[_]Data') or (name LIKE '%[_]R8[_]Data'))`, But `%[_]Data` works fine, and the latter doesn't, do you know why?

Comment: @zdev - I think it is because the query optimizer decided to first filter down the rows using your like statement before it tried to apply the datediff condition. You really can't be sure in what order the where clauses will be evaluated. The error happens the query try to do a datediff for a table name that does not match your pattern.